# sending emails from different Smtps in different IPs

Tags: domain-name-system, email, smtp, email-server, spf

I sent mails with different Smtps for example Smtp1 on IP 1.1.1.1 and Smtp2 on IP 2.2.2.2 . which my spf record for the From (info@myDoamin.com) part in emails is :

```
spf1 include:mail.mydomain.com +all
```

then I get a warning from yahoo and gmail which more than one entry from this spf is allowed... and it is suspicious to be a spam.

What my correct SPF should be ?

I don't know if I provided enough information about my problem . If needed it would be provided in this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people use MX or A in their SPF record that covers all of your MX Records and A Records

```
v=spf1 mx a -all
```

If you're not sending from your MX records then you can list out the ip4 addresses you send from.

The best way to create your SPF Record, if you're not sure is to use an [SPF Wizard](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/spfwizard/)

You'll go through the questionnaire and it will produce the record that you need.

Comment: you mean if I use all my MX Records and A Records in SPF as you mentioned, then myDomain.com is permitted to send on behalf of all my other domains which myDomain.com has my other domains' MX Records and A Records?

Comment: All the MX and A records (Attached to myDomain in DNS) are permitted to send on behalf of myDomain.com.

Answer (score 1):

If you just have those two IP-addresses sending mail for the mydomain.com domain, your SPF record should look like this:

```
v=spf1 ip4:1.1.1.1 ip4:2.2.2.2 -all
```

Do not use +all in a SPF record, since that allow the whole internet to send mail from your domain. In the final SPF record you should use `-all` to indicate that ONLY the listed entries are allowed to send mail. With `~all` you can indicate that the listed entries are allowed to send mail, but their might also be others sending legitimate mails.

The include mechanism is normally used to allow others to send mails from your domains. E.g. if you are using a newsletter service, you can include their SPF record with the include mechanism (`include:spf.mailerservice.tld`)

Comment: what about if I have many IPs? What would be my SPF record in this case ?

Comment: I don't want to list all my IP addresses or domain names in SPF record. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: If your IPs are in a range (e.g. 1.1.1.0 - 1.1.1.15) you can use the CIDR notation to list the addresses (e.g. `ip4:1.1.1.0/28` - http://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr), or you can use the approach from the answer from @henry.